# Why a device does not receive push notification on background?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

On iOS10 when an app is opened I'm receiving Push Notifications, but when I press home button and app is on background mode - it does not receive anything.

My code is:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], completionHandler: { (granted: Bool, error: NSError?) in

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

// Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

}
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
    print("User Info => ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

So I cannot find where the problem is? Any idea? Or there is something new in iOS10?

I already turned on these features:

[image]
[image]

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

       completionHandler(.NewData)

    }

need background fetch

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this

[image]
 and this

[image]

Please confirm after doing these, i will edit this answer accordingly

Comment: is the .pem u generated working properly? please use the terminal to check if there is proper SSL handshake on production/sandbox server.
Although highly unlikely coz you are getting push while app is in foreground, still its good to retrace the steps

Comment: \Can be a reason that in `entitlement` I have only `APS Environment — Development`?

Comment: shouldnt be, as probably you are testing it in development mode, apns - sandbox, but as i said, its best to retrace the steps

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

       completionHandler(.NewData)    

    } use a background fetch above code in swift 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Try with this steps for iOS 10,

- > First of all In the **targets -> Capabilities -> enable Push Notifications** to add Push Notifications Entitlements.
- > Second one Implement **UserNotifications.framework** into your app. Import UserNotifications.framework in your **AppDelegate**.

  ## import < UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h >

  @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder   < UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate >

  @end
- > Third step - Inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method assign UIUserNotificationSettings and implement UNUserNotificationCenter delegate.

  ## define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

  ```
  if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")){
      UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
      center.delegate = self;
      [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
           if( !error ){
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
           }
       }];  
  }
    return YES;
  }
  ```

  - > Last step - implement this two delegate methods.

//====================For iOS 10====================

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

    //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app. 

    NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

   //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.

   NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);

}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Thanks.